# Error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Tags: android, kotlin

I m running to a weird problem with my api response i m using retrofit to execute the request and observing the data using rxjava observabl , i checked my code over and over but nothing is working for me , i don't know what is wrong

- This is the json file

```
[
  {
     "country":"World",
     "cases":13854510,
     "todayCases":170435,
     "deaths":589937,
     "todayDeaths":3727,
     "recovered":8241308,
     "active":5023265,
     "critical":59929,
     "casesPerOneMillion":1777,
     "deathsPerOneMillion":75,
     "totalTests":0,
     "testsPerOneMillion":0
  }
]
```

*This is my model class

```
class CountryModel(

   var active: String?,
   var cases: String?,
   var casesPerOneMillion: String?,
   var country: String?,
   var critical: String?,
   var deaths: String?,
   var recovered: String?,
   var todayCases: String?,
   var todayDeaths: String?

)
class wrapCountryModel(var countries : ArrayList<CountryModel>)
```

- This is my interface for the api call

```
   @GET("countries")
   fun getCountriesData() : Flowable<wrapCountryModel>
```

- Retrofit Singleton

```
fun getCountriesStats() : Observable<wrapCountryModel>{

       return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Utilities.COUNTRIESAPILINK)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
           .build().create(ApiInterface::class.java).getCountriesData()
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).toObservable()

   }
```

- This is the final Step getting data

```
RetrofitSingleton().getCountriesStats().subscribe(object : Observer<wrapCountryModel>{
          override fun onComplete() {

          }

          override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

          }

          override fun onNext(t: wrapCountryModel) {
              val country = t.countries[0].country
              val cases = t.countries[0].cases
              val todaycases = t.countries[0].todayCases
              val deaths = t.countries[0].deaths
              val todaydeath = t.countries[0].todayDeaths
              val recovered =  t.countries[0].recovered
              val critical =  t.countries[0].critical
              val active =  t.countries[0].active
              val casesPerOneMillion =  t.countries[0].casesPerOneMillion

              val countryModel  = 

CountryModel(country!!,cases!!,todaycases!!,deaths!!,todaydeath!!,recovered!!,critical!!,active!!,casesPerOneMillion!!)

              iView.getCountriesList(arrayListOf(countryModel))
          }
```

Any Help is appreciated , thank you

Comment: i have many entires actually because the gson file is too large , i just decided to paste the first part of it  , but what is the issue , i don't understand what is causing the exception

Comment: can you please show a piece of code on how the model class should be formed ?